# How to properly parse JSON in Notepad++ for JSON that that saved using Python?

Tags: python, json, notepad++

I have a `dict` that was saved as `JSON` in `Python`, which is as shown in the code below.

```
import json
# https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/python-tutorial/python-json/
person_dict = {
  "name": "xxxx",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "divorced": False,
  "children": ("Ann","Billy"),
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
    {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
  ]
}


tt_json=json.dumps(person_dict)
with open ('data.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump (tt_json, f)
```

Then, I would like to view the `data.json` in `Notepad++`. However, using plugin `JavaScript Map Parser` or `JSON Viewer` ,the JSON was rendered as below

[image]

Whereas, I would expect the plugin `JavaScript Map Parser` or `JSON Viewer` to render the JSON  as below.

[image]

It seem, the issue is due to the JSON that was saved with Python was enclosed with  the double quote `"{ ... }"`.

```
"\"\\n{\\n  \\\"name\\\": \\\"xxxx\\\",\\n  \\\"age\\\": 30,\\n  \\\"married\\\": True,\\n  \\\"divorced\\\": False,\\n  \\\"children\\\": (\\\"Ann\\\",\\\"Billy\\\"),\\n  \\\"pets\\\": None,\\n  \\\"cars\\\": [\\n    {\\\"model\\\": \\\"BMW 230\\\", \\\"mpg\\\": 27.5},\\n    {\\\"model\\\": \\\"Ford Edge\\\", \\\"mpg\\\": 24.1}\\n  ]\\n}\\n\""
```

May I know how to resolve this issue either in Notepad++ or by tweaking on  how the JSON is saved in Python.

Note that, this JSON will be saved in Python, and later requires some manual modification in Notepad++, and re-open again in Python.

p.s.
Thanks to [venky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5660284/venky). Using the proposed solution, the JSON presented as a single liner in Notepad++

[image]

But, the JSON can be pretified using the JSTool using the setting below:

[image]

which will present the JSON as below:
[image]

Comment: You’re dumping your dict *twice* to JSON, so what you get is a JSON string containing a JSON object. Remove that `json.dumps` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting dictionary to JSON and then again to JSON using `JSON.dump` twice.
Just use it once while writing the file.

```
import json
person_dict = {
  "name": "xxxx",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "divorced": False,
  "children": ("Ann","Billy"),
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
    {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
  ]
}

with open ('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(person_dict, f)
```

[image]